# Is there an inverse to the rs-convert function that can convert from ply to bag?

Tags: unity-game-engine, ros, realsense, bag

I want to test a program I made for Realsense in unity using an RGBD dataset. The ones I downloaded come in the `.ply` format. `rs-convert` can be used to take in a `.bag` file and  convert it to a `.ply`. Is there something that can do the inverse, convert from `.ply` to `.bag`?

Comment: hm why? A `.ply` are polygons that have been calculated/estimated from a given `.bag` point cloud ... There is no real way to go back and extract the exact original point cloud from the polygons again ... You **could** probably take the polygon and from it generate some point cloud with enough information to recreate the polygon again ... but what exactly are you trying to achieve by that?

Comment: @derHugo I'm trying to use RGBD datasets to evaluate an algorithm that runs on realsense camera in unity. I want to have a controlled testing environment with common datasets. Are there any `.bag` datasets?

Comment: Could give it a shot at https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/blob/master/doc/sample-data.md

Comment: that should work. I'll update my post with an answer if everything works fine. Thanks for the help @derHugo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is through meshlab. Converting to an obj file for unity. Which worked for my purpose. There isn't a clean way to get ply to bag, but obj or another format can be used in place of the realsense SDK.